# How to recover from

Tags: centos, docker

Running Docker 1.3.2 on CentOS 6.6.

How can I recover from this error state?

Restarting Docker did not help

```
docker run -p 8888:6543 zopyx/pp.server
Unable to find image 'zopyx/pp.server' locally
Pulling repository zopyx/pp.server
e64a47ccffa6: Error pulling image (latest) from zopyx/pp.server, Driver devicemapper failed to create image rootfs 39339148edaf62e7572fc761b22a06a1b6320117360de99169150300f798e68f: device 39339148edaf62e7572fc761b22a06a1b6320117360de99169150300f798e68f already exists 0117360de99169150300f798e68f already exists
fe95bf7d5f50: Download complete
9a4594fe74ea: Download complete
8c4b1edcceea: Download complete
ed5a78b7b42b: Download complete
f05fd44c10df: Download complete
4a52e4389d94: Download complete
6a6f3cabfcc0: Download complete
4c7a3dc214a2: Download complete
c444afe7e4a7: Download complete
071ab5784dd2: Download complete
6f723dfb9672: Download complete
eef4e9a4e524: Download complete
cab477dc84b8: Download complete
435c43b2ac8c: Download complete
3759d2f133f4: Download complete
bf8ebe5cdfab: Download complete
503797f1ffc0: Download complete
165b1bc94202: Download complete
39339148edaf: Error downloading dependent layers
2015/01/01 16:15:28 Error pulling image (latest) from zopyx/pp.server, Driver devicemapper failed to create image rootfs 39339148edaf62e7572fc761b22a06a1b6320117360de99169150300f798e68f: device 39339148edaf62e7572fc761b22a06a1b6320117360de99169150300f798e68f already exists
```

Comment: Same problem here. Mine occured due to a failed download from the repo, that seems to have left some residue.

Comment: After running service docker restart, the error message changes slightly:
Driver devicemapper failed to create image rootfs 511136ea3c5a64f264b78b5433614aec563103b4d4702f3ba7d4d2698e22c158: Error running DeviceCreate (createSnapDevice) dm_task_run failed

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue following a docker build that ran into a disk space issue.  It seems that various garbage is left behind.  Reboot doesn't fix.  A sledgehammer fix is to just delete everything under /var/lib/docker (save anything you need first).  Everything is reinstated by the next build run.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been seen by other people too [See Issue 3721](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3721).

The two common causes are low disk space and slow network. The slow network cause was marked as fixed in a version of docker earlier than the one you have listed as your versions so I suspect it is a disk space issue.

If it is not a disk space issue you can try to delete the image from your local drive and the try again:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<id>
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/graph/<id>
```

Where id is `39339148edaf62e7572fc761b22a06a1b6320117360de99169150300f798e68f`

Comment: Diskspace is not the issues...and why do you send a question as answer?

Comment: Rephrased and added details

Comment: The cause was diskspace in my case, you are right. Emptying the graph directory wasn't enough and I don't have an '/aufs/' directory in my /var/lib/docker

Comment: Searching the filesystem for <id> gave me /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/<id> and /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/metadata/<id> but removing them didn't solve the problem.